# /usr/bin/time for Nvidia GPU utilization of program

Tags: nvidia, gpu

Is there a command-line program like `/usr/bin/time` that can report on Nvidia GPU utilization of a program?

I'd like to get something like the following, that also includes `GPU time (seconds)`, `Percent of GPU time this job got`, and/or power consumed.  I believe the closest thing might be `nvidia-smi`, but it seems like it can only report on current GPU utilization and not aggregate over the run of a program.

```
$ /usr/bin/time --verbose python -c 'for i in range(int(1e8)): pass;'
    Command being timed: "python -c for i in range(int(1e8)): pass;"
    User time (seconds): 5.99
    System time (seconds): 1.66
    Percent of CPU this job got: 99%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:07.68
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 3189148
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 796317
    Voluntary context switches: 1
    Involuntary context switches: 302
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```